# Testing Linux HTB fall short of expectation

Tags: linux, networking, unix, traffic-shaping

I am trying to test Linux [HTB](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-htb), doing the simplest example just to see it actually works.

I am creating a root and giving it **200kbps**, then I create 3 classes which each one gets assigned a portion of the **200kbps**.

```
              - Root -
             /   |    \
            /    |     \
           /     |      \
          /      |       \
         /       |        \
        /        |         \
    100kbps    60kbps     40kbps
```

What I want to see at the end is that when they run for 60 seconds I get that
first class used half of the bandwidth, second one 30% of the bandwidth and the last class used 20% of the bandwidth.

---

Now comes the setting up for the test.

I created the above tree, and applied the filters.

```
tc qdisc add dev eno2 root handle 1: htb default 30
tc class add dev eno2 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 200kbps ceil 200kbps
tc class add dev eno2 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 100kbps ceil 200kbps
tc class add dev eno2 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 60kbps ceil 200kbps
tc class add dev eno2 parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 40kbps ceil 200kbps
tc filter add dev eno2 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 80 0xffff flowid 1:10
tc filter add dev eno2 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 25 0xffff flowid 1:20
tc filter add dev eno2 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 36 0xffff flowid 1:30
```

For the testing I used [iperf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf).
I opened 3 terminals for the servers:

```
sudo iperf -s -p 25 -i 1
sudo iperf -s -p 36 -i 1
sudo iperf -s -p 80 -i 1
```

Then connected the 3 clients with a parameter of how much time to run (60 seconds).

```
iperf -c 132.74.120.45 -p 25 -t 60
iperf -c 132.74.120.45 -p 36 -t 60
iperf -c 132.74.120.45 -p 80 -t 60
```

---

Results are a bit odd... it seems that each used the same amount of bandwidth regardless of the original allocation ?
[image]

Furthermore, I did check the queue discipline is HTB using `bmon` command as you can see in the picture below. 
[image]

---

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the 132.74.120.45 (the one you're running iperf in server mode) third server? Are all connections going through your HTB shaper host eno2 as outgoing traffic?

Comment: @JaroslavKucera, thanks for your response, I typed on my computer `ifconfig` and saw eno2 with and ip so I used them. I am not an expert in networking. I hope it was a right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTB traffic shaping only works on outgoing devices. So if you want to test the functionality, you have to test it against the destination which can be reached through the shaped interface. See the drawing:

```
PC---\
PC----switch----(eno1)router with HTB shaping(eno2)----Internet
PC---/                                        ^^^^ 
                               Shaping is done on the ougtoing device
```

So the traffic on the internal network isn't limited. Only the traffic, which goes outside the network (through eno2 in this case) is limited with HTB queuing discipline.